# Python binance client.create_test_order returning nothing with no error

Tags: python, cryptocurrency, binance, binance-api-client

I'm trying to use the python-binance api to trade Ethereum, whilst developing the code I've been using the `create_test_order` function so that I'm not costing myself money to run tests.

The issue I'm getting however is that the function doesn't seem to be returning anything at all:

```
try:
    avg_price = float(client.get_avg_price(symbol="ETHGBP")['price'])
    logging.info(f"Test Buy at {avg_price}")
    order = client.create_test_order(
            symbol="ETHGBP",
            side=SIDE_BUY,
            type=ORDER_TYPE_LIMIT,
            timeInForce=TIME_IN_FORCE_GTC,
            quantity=100,
            price="{:.2f}".format(float(avg_price)))
    logging.info(order)
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(f"Exception occurred: {e}", exc_info=True)
    quit()
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
travis_1  | 2021-05-27 15:08:02,617 - root - INFO - Test Buy at 2003.53136248
travis_1  | 2021-05-27 15:08:02,852 - root - INFO - {}
```

I've been following this guide through, and I was expecting the returned order to have something in it, but it's not: https://algotrading101.com/learn/binance-python-api-guide/

I'm also confused that it's returning nothing, but no exception is being raised.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation `create_test_order` returns empty JSON object `{}`.

See: https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binance.html?highlight=create_test_order#binance.client.AsyncClient.create_test_order

Answer (score 0):

According to the python-binance documentation, the create_test_order() method only returns an opening and closing empty brackets (Empty JSON Object). Look at the attached picture below:

[image]

Documentation link: https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binance.html